# Timeout in COM communication

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, serial-port, com-port

I have a device that connect to computer and communicate with the computer via a COM port.

I tested it with 2 different computer. It works properly in Windows-Server 2008, but return timeout in Windows-7 ultimate in another system! Why?

Windows-7 :

[image]

Windows-Server-2008 :

[image]

Note :It doesn't need any driver! (I guess)

Comment: run the tool as admin: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token

Comment: I already did it! not works!